# Has mainnet websocket address support been discontinued?

Tags: mainnet

"ws://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"

Are you no longer supporting this address?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to use `wss` instead of `ws`. That will (usually) fix your problem.

`wss://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I solved it by assigning a new wss address using quicknode.